# How can setup dynamic buffersize for BufferedReader in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, streaming, size, buffer

I am testing data streaming from client to server. It generates random doubles and integers and send them to server; the server must read them until user stops it.

But it seems to be always stopped around 2426th data has been read by the server.

The client:

```
    while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) 
    {

        ...                     
        else 
        {
          while(!bStop)
          {
                ins++;
                dUserInput = rRandom.nextDouble();
                out.println(ins +", " + dUserInput);   
          }
           .....   
         }
```

The server:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()), buffersize); 

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
   ...
 System.out.println("recv> " + inputLine);
}
```

The output:

```
....
recv> 2421, 0.791175426456302
recv> 2422, 0.1424806550326747
recv> 2423, 0.32742036805153263
recv> 2424, 0.07852028188946414
recv> 2425, 0.8438837153559341
recv> 2426, 0.8548109748012377
```

I removed ',buffersize' from BufferedReader(), it stops at 2426th data even if the boolean 'bStops' of the client is still false. I wonder there is a buffer size problem.

If the client is disconnected after stopped at the 2426th data, the server output is showing much data after the 2426th and error messages. One of them is about buffer size.

Any ideas? Do I have to use DataInputStream instead of BufferedReader?

Thanks,

Comment: To make it easier for answerers, please fill in the missing parts of the pasted code so that it can actually compile. That doesn't mean to paste your original code; just put something simple there. In other words, don't put unnecessary burden on those who would like to help.

Comment: Also, since you are already aware of DataInputStream, have you tried it? You should also use DataOutputStream on the client side.

Comment: I used BufferedReader and pipes instead of sockets, and the count went up to 186086 without any issues. What error are you getting? Paste the buffer size error and everything above it.

Comment: I did another trial using tcp sockets, with and without the buffersize argument. Please post runnable code of client and server that causes the issue. Also mention your platform and java version. Are client and server on the same subnet? If not, how many hops are there? Use traceroute. Does ping drop packets often? Try running client & server on the same machine.

Comment: Thanks for inputs. I will try pipes.

Comment: Thanks for many comments; actually there was a loop condition error in the server side. I fixed it after read your comment. I didn't suspect the condition that is not in this code was wrong. Now the sever is able to receive chunk of data until user stops.